# How to Install android SDK in ubuntu server

Tags: android, ubuntu, react-native, gradle, gradlew

I have a react native project in ubuntu server, and I want to build an android app for production. to do that I first have to generate Gradle Wrapper files so I run this command in `android` directory

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version <my-gradle-version>
```

After I run this command I got this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I know how to define SDK location with `sdk.dir` in the `local.properties` file or with an `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable.

But my problem is SDK isn't installed

> My question is in react native which sdk I need to build an android app for production and how to install it in ubuntu server

Comment: Is android studio installed in your PC?

Comment: No, I have ubuntu server

Comment: Please follow the instruction for building react native project in Linux : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try This :

## download latest android sdk

cd /opt

```
wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz

tar -xvf android-sdk*-linux.tgz

cd android-sdk-linux/tools

./android update sdk --no-ui --filter platform,platform-tools
```

## set path

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools' >> /etc/profile.d/android.sh

echo 'export ANDROID_TOOLS=/opt/android-sdk-linux' >> /etc/profile.d/android.sh
source /etc/profile.d/android.sh
```

## add i386 support

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386

apt-get update

apt-get install -y libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

## install sdks

```
cd /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools

./android list sdk --all

./android update sdk --no-ui --all
```

Comment: How can I check the latest version of the android sdk? I think the "android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz" might be outdated by now

Comment: @lcsvcn this might be helpful https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager

Comment: I've installed SDK correctly, but when I run ***flutter doctor --android-licenses*** I get ***Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to resolve this.*** flutter doctor -v says ***Android SDK at /opt/android-sdk-linux*** how can I fix this?