# How to Install flutter SDK in ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, gradle, flutter

How to install Flutter in the Ubuntu server? I followed this way to install android sdk in Ubuntu Server. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51745553/8822337 How to install flutter like this?

Official Installation link. https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
# home directory
cd ~

# install dependencies, git, clone flutter
sudo apt-get install -yf libglu1-mesa git
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

# Add to .profile, reload
echo "export PATH=\$PATH:\$HOME/flutter/bin" >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile

# Accept licenses (interactive):
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

That should really be it. If you need virtualization, do `apt-get install qemu-kvm cpu-checker` and run `kvm-ok` to see if KVM is available.